# Get All Filtered Data (not only what is displayed in current page)

Tags: javascript, jquery

my input tag

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MyInput").on("keyup", function () {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myTablee tr").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="MyInput" type="text" placeholder="search">
```

">
this code returns only data filtered in the current page and i want to return all data in the same pagination